# How to get Event type from UISwitch in IOS

Tags: ios

I want to get event when click on switch for that i made coding like following but i am getting event always null. what is the issue? how can we achieve?

```
UISwitch *simpleSwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRect){ CGPointZero, { self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height }}];
        [simpleSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(eventHandler:event:) UIControlEventValueChanged];
        [self addSubview:simpleSwitch];

#pragma mark -  handler event methods
- (void)eventHandler:(id)sender event:(UIEvent *)event  {
    NSLog(@"Event type: %@",[event class]);
}
```

Comment: I'd write: `[simpleSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(eventHandler:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventValueChanged];` and `(void)eventHandler:(id)sender`

Comment: Any specific reason for inclusion of UIEvent? Infact I have never used it till date.

Comment: Why do you need the UIEvent object ?

Comment: @Larme While I always use the form you suggest, the signature used by the OP is perfectly valid. The event that triggered the action is supposed to be sent in such a case; at least according to the documentation. I can't find anything in the docs that explains why a `nil` event is being sent when used with a `UISwitch`.